# vsftpd not starting

Tags: configuration, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd on Ubuntu Raring Ringtail, and made a few changes to the config file.

When I try to run with these changes, the service never starts.

Reverting to default config, the service then runs.

[Here is my config file](http://pastebin.com/6C2R4b67)

I got the changes from this guide:  [Howto: Easy FTP with vsftpd](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293&s=f0bc96c4bd77f0a6881ae4a405c8c567&p=3138955#post3138955)

I can't figure out the problem, as I don't know what half of it means...

Comment: can you post some log outputs pls?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any log...

Comment: in the configuration file, set "syslog_enable" to YES restart the daemon! and output the log with "tail /var/log/vsftpd.log"

Comment: There is no such log.

Comment: I have the exact same settings as you, except:

ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES

Can you comment these out and try again?  (maybe a problem in your ssl config) Also, put the log file somewhere else E.g. /tmp/vsftpd.log

Answer (score 4):

looking at you config I can see a few minor issues that might be causing it not to start.

First I recommend you shrink down the config file to just the variables you need like the following.

```
listen=YES
listen_port=21
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
syslog_enable=NO
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

for information on what you can use go to https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html

you might want to add a `local_root=/folder/folder` to aviod possible problems but its not required

**remove**

`xferlog_enable=YES`

some reason the default config has it on but the log location off!

its also important to note that `xferlog_enabled` and `syslog_enable` are for **different** logs. seen many people mix these settings and get nothing.

**remove**

`pam_service_name=vsftpd`

since you dont have `guest_enable` in you config file this setting does nothing. Plus other varaibles are needed for PAM to work see

[How to setup virtual users for vsftpd with access to a specific sub directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575523/how-to-setup-virtual-users-for-vsftpd-with-access-to-a-specific-sub-directory/575825#575825)

**remove**

`dirmessage_enable=YES`

you need to provide the `message_file` variable for it to work

**remove**

`listen_port=21` because 21 is the default anyway

`use_localtime=YES` because server time is more reliable

`connect_from_port_20=YES` this is not needed apart from in advanced configurations

also you might want to turn your logs

**change**

`syslog_enable=NO`

to

`syslog_enable=YES`

the resulting config file should be

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
syslog_enable=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

If that doesn't work remove the SSL settings and set a

Answer (score 1):

run

sudo lsof -i | grep ftp

see if any service is using the listen to ftp.
Stop that service.
Now try to run vsftp service.

Comment: you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

to make vsftp log you have to set it on the config file . 
here you have how [edit vsftp to make it log](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/vsftpd-logs-185735/)

after that try to start the service with /etc/init.d/vsftp start

and then check the log with cat /var/log/vsftp.log

finally post the log for better help :D

Comment: The answer should at least include the essential steps given in the link, as it may die.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post now but my install was failing due to the ipv6 element. Not well documented online - uncomment the ipv6 line and change the value to =no

Hope this helps someone